# Assignments using templates in c#

Tags: c#, templates, generics, covariance

```
public class Animal
{

}
public class Cat : Animal
{

}

public class AnimalBag<T> where T : Animal
{

} 

...
AnimalBag<Animal> bag = new AnimalBag<Cat>();
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `AnimalBag<Cat>` to `AnimalBag'

And if I try this:

```
AnimalBag<Animal> bag = (AnimalBag<Animal>) new AnimalBag<Cat>();
```

> Cannot convert type `AnimalBag<Cat>` to `AnimalBag<Animal>`.

How can I resolve this kind of issues in C#? This works perfectly in Java.

Comment: what framework version?

Comment: In the general case this is not possible. It is possible (by using an interface) if *all* the methods that use `T` only return a `T` or if *all* the methods that use `T` only accept it as a parameter. If there is even one method that both accepts and returns a `T` then not possible. So: show your methods.

Comment: If this were allowed then you could write `bag.Add(new Dog())` and add a dog to a bag of cats.  That would be bad, so the compiler doesn't let you do it.

Comment: Here's an [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `AnimalBag<Animal> bag` states that bag will be capable of storing any type of **Animal**. The assignment `= new AnimalBag<Cat>();` contradicts this by saying that it is actually only capable of storing **Cats**. Which is it, as it cannot be both?

Answer (score 1):

This case is where co-variant comes into play, but co-variant does not work with *class*, just only *interface* and *delegate*, so you need to define `interface` for co-variant using `out` keyword:

```
public interface IAnimalBag<out T> where T : Animal
{
}

public class AnimalBag<T> : IAnimalBag<T> where T: Animal
{
}
```

Then you can assign:

```
IAnimalBag<Animal> bag = new AnimalBag<Cat>();
```

You can check more [co-variance and contra-variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) in Generics